# Remap `gc` for vim-commentary not working

Tags: vim

I am trying to write a mapping to use vim Commentary. Right now my `.vimrc` has the following line:

```
vnoremap gg <PLUG>Commentary
```

However, when I open a document to edit pressing `gg` only makes the terminal flash. Using the default mapping `gc` works as expected.

I can see that the mapping is loaded by vim by running `:map gg` which returns

```
v  gg          * <Plug>Commentary
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The terminal flashes because `gg` puts the cursor on the first line of the buffer and you are already there.
- `<Plug>Commentary` is a "plug mapping", a special kind of mapping used by plugin developers as an alternative to exposing the guts of the plugin. Since they are mappings, they can only be consumed in recursive mappings (`nmap`, `xmap`, etc.). They can't be used in non-recursive mappings (`nnoremap`, `xnoremap`, etc.) at all.

  Therefore, your mapping should look like this:

  ```
  xmap gg <Plug>Commentary
  ```

  Note that I have used `xmap`, here, which restricts the mapping to visual mode. You don't really want to trigger it while typing `egg` in select mode.
- But that's one part of the problem. Your mapping is a visual mode mapping so you can't expect it to work in normal mode.

  For `gg` to do what you want in normal mode, you would need another mapping:

  ```
  nmap gg <Plug>Commentary
  ```
- Note that the plugin provides `gc` [in one additional mode](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary/blob/master/plugin/commentary.vim#L114-L118): operator-pending mode, so you will have to do it as well for the sake of completeness:

  ```
  omap gg <Plug>Commentary
  ```
- That said, overriding default commands is not exactly a good idea, especially common ones like `gg`. That is, unless you are an advanced user who uses some other command to do the same but that seems unlikely, here.

Comment: Basically I would really like to use comments with a keystroke/simple set of keystrokes without having to move my hands, hence `gg` came to mind. Based on your second point would you recommend remapping `gc` rather than the plug command?

Comment: How is `gg` better than `gc`?

Comment: Obviously this is very subjective but double tapping g feels more natural than `gc`, which I think matters for something I use so often. Irregardless I think my real question remains re: the choice between using `gc` vs `<Plug>Commentary` as the remap target.

Comment: Well, the plugin's mapping detection logic is severely flawed so you can do either, it doesn't matter.